# Magento 1: how to change the first parameter in cron method

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, cron, model

Here's an interesting one that I learnt today.

I have a module that calls the following method via cron:

```
public function test($test = false, $test2 = false, $test3 = null, $test4 = array())
{
    if (!$test) {
        $test = Mage::getStoreConfig('path/to/config');
    }
    /*
     * Rest of the method
     */
}
```

Basically, **the first parameter `$test` is used by me to make some tests to force the value.**

Never worried too much about until **I found out today that this condition was not working when the cron was triggered**:

```
if (!$test) {
    $test = Mage::getStoreConfig('path/to/config');
}
```

After making some tests I found this bit of code in `Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php` in the `_processJob` method:

```
$callback = array($model, $run[2]);
$arguments = array($schedule);
/* More code here */
call_user_func_array($callback, $arguments);
```

**And `$schedule` is an instance of `Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule`. So the first parameter of my method is always set when the cron job is processed.**

Two questions here:

- **why does Magento send the cron schedule object as a parameter to the cron job method ?**
- how to avoid that behavior / **fix my method without changing its signature** ?

Comment: I have checked all the core of Magento CRON, but couldn't find the use of $schedule object. Now I am also curious about it. :)

Comment: @KeyurShah yes I checked EE but couldn't find anything either

Answer (score 4):

Part of the issue here is that a cron job that accepts a list of arguments is an unusual way to utilize the cron functionality. Because Magento (to my understanding, and I've looked in the core) does not provide a way for you to configure parameters that will be passed to the cron object, it's safe to assume that the implementation of a cron job/function is supposed to be a wrapper for other functions.

In other words, your cron method does not usually do the work itself - it typically will delegate the work to other functions. We see this in the core code; one example would be `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Observer::aggregateSalesReportCouponsData()`, on line 141. Here's a snippet:

```
public function aggregateSalesReportCouponsData($schedule)
{
        Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate(0);
        $currentDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date();
        $date = $currentDate->subHour(25);
        Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/report_rule')->aggregate($date);
        Mage::app()->getLocale()->revert();
        return $this;
}
```

Do you see how the function essentially delegates the work to the `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Resource_Report_Rule::aggregate()` method? While the system does some calculations to get parameters to pass to that method in the original function, the brunt of the work is delegated to another method. I believe that this is the intended use of cron functions in all but the most trivial cases.

Writing your cron functions this way also provides a degree of flexibility to your applications, in that the delegated methods can be then called and reused in other places, instead of having to repeat the functionality.

So, to avoid changing your method signature, use a different function as your cron job function that then calls your current method:

```
public function yourCronJob()
{
    $this->test();
}
```

In answer to your first question, I really don't know why the schedule is passed by default. I think only a member of the original core team could give a definitive answer to that. I haven't actually every seen a cron function that makes use of it.

Comment: Yeah I ended up finding the same solution as you suggest. However, still curious about the reason why this argument is passed.